# How can we remove save changes button from edit manager of a rad grid

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik, client-side, telerik-grid

Work on Asp.net webpage vs2012 C#.Need suggestion how to remove Save changes button from the batch editing manager.Actually I want a **Save Button** is placed outside the grid. I know how to put save button out side the [grid](http://www.telerik.com/forums/batch-editing---need-to-have-the-save-changes-button-outside-the-grid).help me to remove save changes button from the grid edit manager.

I need to change caption of  Cancel changes button to **clear** of a edit manager.

On **Cancel changes** button,is it possible to call a javascript function. I need to show some message not need to do cancel.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove save button, and to change the cancel button text:

```
<CommandItemSettings ShowSaveChangesButton="false" CancelChangesText="Clear"/>
```

I didnt understand what the other thing you want to do, sorry.

Comment: I think this answers his other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28815837/invoke-method-batcheditcommand-from-c-net/